# how to make a hidden div appear on button click in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript, I am trying to make a div appear after the click of a button, i've tried but i don't seem to be getting it right. Below is my JS CODE:

```
let hiddenArea = document.getElementById('hidden-div');


submitButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if(document.getElementById('r1').checked) {
        hiddenArea.style.display = "block";
        arena.style.display='none';
        actionArea.style.display ='none';

    }
    else{
        arena.style.visibility='visible';
        actionArea.style.visibility ='visible';   
        hiddenArea.style.display = "none";
    }
});
```

Here is my HTML code:

```
<p>Do you want to lock? </p>
    <form>
        <input id="r1" type="radio" name="question" value="yes" checked> Yes<br>
        <input id="r2" type="radio" name="question" value="no"> No<br>
        <input id="btn" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form><br><br>
</div>
<div id ="hidden-div"></div>
```

Comment: if you are ok with jquery, then it will make your work more easy.

Comment: The code you've provided is incomplete. You are using undeclared variable names and invalid HTML. Please fix this

Comment: As the `submitButton` is inside the `FORM` element, the form must be getting submitted as a result page must be reloading

Answer (score 3):

```js
let hiddenArea = document.getElementById('hidden-div');
let submitButton = document.getElementById('btn');

submitButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
    if(document.getElementById('r1').checked) {
        hiddenArea.style.display = "block";
     //   arena.style.display='none';
      //  actionArea.style.display ='none';

    }
    else{
     //   arena.style.visibility='visible';
    //    actionArea.style.visibility ='visible';   
        hiddenArea.style.display = "none";
    }
});
```

```html
enter code here 


<p>Do you want to lock? </p>
          <form>
            <input id="r1" type="radio" name="question" value="yes" checked> Yes<br>
            <input id="r2" type="radio" name="question" value="no"> No<br>
            <input id="btn" type="submit" value="Submit">
          </form><br><br>

      </div>
      <div id ="hidden-div">Hidden</div>
```

You should turn off the default behavior off button `e.preventDefault();`.

Comment: how do i do that? can you please explain, thank you. i'd tried commenting out like you  did in your code, yet it did not work

Comment: No need to comment any code add an event parameter then `e.preventDefault()`

Answer (score 1):

An alternative would be:
`$('#yourDivID').toggle();`
If you want it to switch between `show` and `hidden`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this i hope this will work for you

```
var element=document.getElementById('target');
element.style.display = 'none';           // Hide
element.style.display = 'block';          // Show
element.style.display = 'inline';         // Show
element.style.display = 'inline-block';   // Show
```

**in JQuery the following code will work for you.**

```
$('#youDivID').hide();
$('#youDivID').show();

$('.youDivClassName').hide();
$('.youDivClassName').show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone that contributed, finally, I was able to solve the visibility problem I had in my code with the help of dev tool, I was able to see through dev tool that div in question was answerable to (1)***.display ="none"***, and (2) ***.visibility="visible"*** when the button was clicked, so . display property was taking precedence over .visibility.

I was able to correct this by chosen one of the props. See my JS code below:

```
hiddenArea.style.visibility = "hidden";



submitButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
        if(document.getElementById('r1').checked) {
            hiddenArea.style.visibility = "visible";
            arena.style.display='none';
            actionArea.style.display ='none';


        }
        else {
            arena.style.visibility='visible';
            actionArea.style.visibility ='visible';   
            hiddenArea.style.display = "none";
```